How can I use one router to route between two subnets?
I have a basic subnetting question -- please bear with me as I am still learning.  I wanted to use my router with IP address 192.168.1.1/24 to route between two hosts on my LAN which are on separate subnets. PC 1 has an IP of 192.168.1.2/24 and PC 2 is 192.168.2.2/24 as shown in the following image:
diagram of network
I was able to set a static route on the router so I am able to ping PC 2 from PC 1. However, it does not work the other way around. I wanted to assign a second LAN IP address on the other subnet to the router (e.g. 192.168.2.1) but I can't figure out a way to do it on my home router (TP-Link Archer AX50). Is there any way to achieve the routing both directions (from PC 2 to PC 1 and vice versa) with any one router, and if so, how can I change my current configuration to make it work? Or would that require a second router on the 192.168.2.0/24 network?  Thanks

What's the real goal here? As in, what did you think you would gain to have two IP subnets? (Note: under pretty much no circumstances there would be a point to use/have two IP subnets in one broadcast domain, i.e., the simple switch that has no VLAN support whatsoever that a majority of consumer-grade / home routers consist of.)

so as a general rule, you really need a commercial/enterprise grade router to route between more than two networks (the LAN and the WAN). As this appears to be a Consumer-grade device, i really have to recommend against this approach. These devices have just two interfaces, the LAN (which has multiple ports) and the WAN.

it does not work the other way around I'm pretty sure it does work, as in, you have already configure some sort of route on PC2 that can ultimately leads traffics for 192.168.1.x to corresponding hosts like PC1 (i.e., the "prefix route" 192.168.2.0/24 is not the only relevant route that has been added on PC2), otherwise it wouldn't have work the "original way" either. The reason "it does not work" is probably just PC1 has firewall that blocks ICMP echo requests (but not replies).

Thanks to both of you, that's what I needed to know. I know this situation isn't functionally very useful, but I was trying to understand subnets and routing a bit better.

A host's default gateway must be on the same subnet as the host. So the host on the 192.168.2.0/24 subnet cannot use 192.168.1.1 as its default gateway, since that's on the 192.168.1.0/24 subnet.

@Spiff In fact on at least Linux, if a route is added with its gateway being an IP that is configured on the host / router itself, it would work like a direct route that has the interface that the IP is configured on being the route interface. (I wondered how the OP could have added the route and I tried it on my computer.)

But indeed, semantically speaking it probably doesn't make much sense to add such a route. (Or even, there's hardly a reason to.) The general sense is that, you use a "neighbor" (or "local" in the sense of "local area network") IP as the gateway of a route for "remote" ("not your LAN") destination(s). (That's also why it makes little to no sense to use more than one IP subnet in your LAN.)

@TomYan OP said he put the static route on the router, not PC2. PC2 still has an invalid IP config because its default gateway is not on PC2's subnet. There are sensible reasons to have more than one subnet on a single Ethernet LAN, even with them all being served by a single router, but that single router must have an IP address on each local subnet for which it is expected to act as the default gateway.
